# 18.04 Browsers Gone

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

So I am relatively new to the whole linux concept but I have had a few troubles. I have gotten past a few of them but today a few of my applications just disappeared. I haven’t checked to see all the ones that disappeared but the first ones I saw was that my google chrome stable was gone, along with my mozilla firefox. I’ve searched ask ubuntu and other sources but I can’t seem to find an answer. B

Below I will explain when it Happened:

I was on discord and watching a twitch stream on google chrome. I wanted to find a way to install Starcraft 2 on ubuntu so I started following a reddit post. While I was following the instructions I realized that my favorite applications bar was a bit shorter. I looked over and normally my google chrome icon is at the top and shows the chrome symbol. Now, it was at the bottom and the symbol was that of a .exe file. I was very confused so I promptly restarted my pc (might not have been the best idea). When booting ubuntu it showed one of those black and white terminal-like text screens which hasn’t happened before. I got in and my applications were still gone. I installed mozilla firefox again and did my research but found nought. I then went to install my chrome stable which had now disappeared from the applications store. I am now asking here.

I’m sorry if that was a bit too long but I wanted to give every detail for maybe that could be of more help. Has anybody encountered this before or have a solution?

edit:
I have run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` . After completing `sudo apt update` i received the following text.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Now I also ran the command `apt-cache policy firefox` and I do not know what I should be looking for, but it says "Installed: (none)" even tho I clearly have it installed. The other this that I was told to check was `/var/log/apt/history.log` yet I see no commands that should have done this.

Now I will speak more about things discovered. When I searched my computer files for Google Chrome, my package came up so when I clicked on it, the software store came up with google chrome. After installing, I can see that all of my data is fine but It cannot play a video. When trying to play a video it says "Audio renderer error. Please restart your computer." This only happens on google chrome since I can play videos with ease on Firefox.

I went to go look for more of my applications that had disappeared and I found a few. One of which was the standard text editor that I managed to get back. Another visible thing I saw was that my utilities bundle normally had two lines but now had only one, meaning I had lost five programs from there. The two ones that I know are the disk storage, and the application used for partitions and partition management.

I have found however, so far everything that was removed can be found on the applications store. A new issue that was encountered is that when trying to re-install the application "To Do", it gives me the prompt, "Unable to install 'To Do': The following packages have unmet dependencies:". However this doesn't actually list the packages so I am stumped on that.

Comment: I would explore what packages you removed in the session(s) before this occurred. If you remove packages that was requirements for certain packages (inc. firefox, chrome ..) then when next 'clean' is performed all packages that had *depends* rules will also be removed... ie . looking for an error made days-week+ before hand that created the *ticking time bomb* as a consequence.  I'd look back in `/var/log/apt/history.log` & read the responses to `apt` or package commands more closely (never use '-y' to accept things as that's often when problems like this occur, not straight away but later)

Comment: It looks like you went off the rails when you "started following a reddit post".  Can you elaborate on what exactly you did to your system here?  Also, how did you install chrome in the first place? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265622/edit) your question with the outputs of `apt-cache policy firefox`,  `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, so we can try to figure out what's going on. (So we can actually read it: please retain line breaks and format each line as `code` with four spaces in front of each line)

Comment: I edited it but I don't know how much more help that will be. Sorry for the hassle and thanks for the help